# With $\lambda_1\alpha_1+\lambda_2\alpha_2+\cdots+\lambda_n\alpha_m=0$,how to show the existence of such an $\alpha$ that $(\alpha,\alpha_k)>0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be an n-dimensional inner product space over the field $\mathbb{R}$.Suppose vectors $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_m\in V$ satisfy the following property:If there exist nonegative real numbers $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_m$such that $\lambda_1\alpha_1+\lambda_2\alpha_2+\cdots+\lambda_n\alpha_m=0$,then $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\cdots=\lambda_m=0$.
Try to prove that there exists such an $\alpha \in V$ that $(\alpha,\alpha_i)>0$ for all $i=1,\cdots,m$.

I have tried hard but without any progress.If the set $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_m$ is linear independent,we can use the Schmidt's progress to show the existence of $\alpha$.Indeed,we let 
\begin{align*}
\beta_1=&\alpha_1,\\
\beta_k=&\alpha_k-\sum_{j<k}\frac{(\alpha_k,\beta_j)}{(\beta_j,\beta_j)}\beta_j\triangleq \alpha_k-\sum_{j<k}C_{jk}\beta_j,~~k=2,\cdots,m
\end{align*}
then the vectors  $\beta_1,\beta_2,\cdots,\beta_m$are  orthogonal to each other.Let 
\begin{align*}
\gamma_1=&\alpha_1\\
\gamma_k=&\gamma_{k-1}+\mu_k \beta_k~~k=2,\cdots,m
\end{align*}
where all  ${\mu_k}'s$ will be determined.Let $\alpha=\gamma_m$,then 
\begin{align*}
(\alpha,\alpha_k)=(\gamma_m,\alpha_k)=(\gamma_m,\beta_k+\sum_{j<k}C_{jk}\beta_j)
=\mu_k+\sum_{j<k}C_{jk}\mu_j
\end{align*}
So we can determine  all  ${\mu_k}'s$ Recursively:
\begin{align*}
\mu_1=1,\mu_k>-\sum_{j<k}C_{jk}\mu_j,
\end{align*}
and such an $\alpha$ is what we need.

Comment: What is the relationship between m and n?

Comment: They are irrelevant.

Comment: Your statement seems to have a typo.  The first and third occurrences have $\lambda_m$ while the second has $\lambda_n$.

Comment: Yes,I'm sorry .

Comment: Please correct!

Comment: Done! And I have got one answer!Try to use Gordan’s theorem of alternative.